# octave log2 function shows error

Tags: octave

I am using log2 function in Octave to calculate log2 values of a simple array.

```
>> x = [1:5]
x =

   1   2   3   4   5

>> log2(x)
error: invalid use of script D:\All_Data\my_data\backup3\backup3\tech\DSP\log2.m in index expression
```

I am not sure why Octave is bailing out with error in this case ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have a script that is called `log2.m` in your running directory, which prevents octave from calling its own `log2` function.

I assume that is the case because `D:\All_Data\my_data\backup3\backup3\tech\DSP\log2.m`
doesn't look like a path where standard octave library functions would be installed.

I recommend changing the name of the script in your running directory.